# File write encoding doesn't work

Tags: c#, encoding

I tried to write a file with cyrillic text using the corresponding encoding. But it doesn't work.
Notepad is showing weird characters and Notepad++ doesn't recognize it either.

Here is the line of code I'm using:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Path\Encoding.txt", "дЖЖд", Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251"));
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try not using the encoding parameter at all, since c# use Unicode by default.

Comment: The problem is, the target software that needs to read this file requires non-unicode at first glance.

Comment: have you tried dropping the encoding part: `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\Encoding.txt", "дЖЖд");` works for me, and I can read it in notepad++

Comment: Neither Notepad nor Notepad++ have any special knowledge that the text file contain text in a non-standard encoding.  So there is nothing they can do but pick the equivalent of Encoding.Default.  Which makes it look funny on your machine.  But not on a machine located in Eastern Europe and Russia et al.  If the app you are trying to feed is hard-coded to assume 1251 then it will all come to a good end anyway.

Comment: Have you tried actually changing Notepad++ to Encoding -> Character Sets -> Cyrillic -> Windows 1251 ?

Comment: @MongZhu If you leave out the encoding part, it gets saved as UTF-8 by default.

Comment: @Jirajha It shows it correctly, however the target software cannot recognize it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the answer. That means actually, there is nothing to do as it depends on the target machine.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't need to do anything, like Hans says. You must assume that the target is a legacy application using ANSI text, running on a PC that is using the correct 1251 locale.